# BIOS requires password which was nulled

Tags: bios, password-recovery

In BIOS (Acer emachines e730 specific one) I found that it asks for password as I knew it I decided to remove it. There was option to change password so I did that, but instead of filling new password I left empty fields... Now it asks for password and if I don't enter nothing it's not right...

Old password does not work too. How can I overcome this situation?

Answer (score 2):

1:
 There are some backdoor passwords which the manufacturing company had set that will be accepted by the BIOS. You will just need to know the make of your BIOS. Try out the passwords from these lists.

List of Award BIOS backdoor passwords:BIOSTAR, AWARD_SW, AWARD SW, AWARD PW, CONDO, LKWPETER, J262, 01322222

List of AMI BIOS backdoor passwords: AMI, AAAMMMIII, BIOS, PASSWORD, A.M.I., CONDO

List of PHOENIX BIOS backdoor passwords: phoenix, PHOENIX, CMOS, BIOS

2: To open your laptop please follow these [videos](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=Acer%20emachines%20e730%20cmos%20clearing) dedicated to CMSO clearing or this video to disassemble your model http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=ghSf6ALBUV4

3:Try to locate the CMOS jumper on board. Set the jumper from pin 1-2 to 2-3 and return it back to 1-2.. This will restart your PC to default settings and erase the password.
If you find battery rather than jumpers, try to disconnect it for 2-3 seconds. In some case it is required to give a power cycle to machine without jumper/battery.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You will need to [remove the CMOS battery](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000239.htm) and put it back in. This will have the effect of clearing the BIOS' "memory" and will reset the password. (I'm pretty sure this also resets the BIOS clock. You can set that in the BIOS settings).

Answer (score 0):

I also suffered the same problem but after investing my whole day on this topic I finally unlocked my Bios. The first thing I can suggest is you please don't go for a paid one time password most of them are a fraud. You can Directly contact service center if your bios do not unlock after trying

- Removing Cmos Battery
- Entering various one-time passwords from different sites.

I can suggest you one thing if none of these works. you can visit the service center that will be cheap and convenient for you or try these [free methods](https://realzindagi.com/how-to-reset-bios-password/) to unlock your bios password.